# Remove common columns from two dataframes by keeping one common column intact

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe1 that contains columns like `'ID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'`.
Now from this, I have created two dataframes,

dataframe2 contains `'ID', 'A', 'C'` and 
dataframe3 contains `'ID', 'B', 'E'` and now 
I want to get a datframe, dataframe4 that gives me the remaining columns from dataframe1 but 'ID' should be there in dataframe4.

that means dataframe4 should contain the columns `'ID', 'D', 'F', 'G'`

In the real dataset, dataframe1 has above 300 columns, and dataframe2 and dataframe3 have above 50 columns each.

so any code specified by columns name will be a bit difficult.

How to do it in short?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code:

```
df4 = df1[['ID'] + [df1.columns.drop(df2.columns.tolist() + df3.columns.tolist())]]
```